# cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument '() -> void'

Tags: ios, swift

I have viewed questions with this same error but can't seem to relate it to my issue. I am running a thread as such:

```
   let ballGen = BallGenerator()

    run(SKAction.repeatForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.run(ballGen.addBall(size.width, size.height)),
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.7),

            ])
    ))
```

`addBall()` function:

```
func addBall(_ screenWidth: CGFloat, _ screenHeight: CGFloat) {

    // code

}
```

on the line  where it runs `ballGen.addBall()` it gives the error:

> cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument '() -> void'

What is going wrong here?

Comment: `SKAction.run(_:)` function expects an `SKAction` for the parameter. But your `addBall(_:_:)` function doesn't return an `SKAction`.

Comment: What SKAction would I return?

Comment: I don't know much about `SKAction`. It's your implementation. You better find out what you need. I just pointed out the error.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, I will figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your addBall function is not returning anything. You should do it like this:

```
func addBall(_ screenWidth: CGFloat, _ screenHeight: CGFloat) -> SKAction {

    return SKAction
}
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'SKAction' to expected argument type '() -> Void'             It is also can use just block 'SKAction.run(<#T##block: () -> Void##() -> Void#>)'. Answer is wrong.